# Link source doesn't match the node and duplicates in nodes don't duplicate links

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout, d3-force-directed

I need a help to fix the D3 force simulation nodes and links, I have 2 questions, can you please help me to the right direction?

**Question 1**: Duplicates in node array doesn't duplicate the traffic, please see below picture, there are 2 "mammals" nodes and 4 mammals connection from mammals, how can I achieve it?

http://jsfiddle.net/3hL48pxg/3/

[image]

```js
var nodes = [
  { id: "mammal", group: 0, label: "Mammals", level: 1 },
  { id: "mammal", group: 0, label: "Mammals", level: 1 },
  { id: "dog"   , group: 0, label: "Dogs"   , level: 2 },
  { id: "cat"   , group: 0, label: "Cats"   , level: 2 },
  { id: "fox"   , group: 0, label: "Foxes"  , level: 2 },
  { id: "elk"   , group: 0, label: "Elk"    , level: 2 },
  { id: "insect", group: 1, label: "Insects", level: 1 },
  { id: "ant"   , group: 1, label: "Ants"   , level: 2 },
  { id: "bee"   , group: 1, label: "Bees"   , level: 2 },
  { id: "fish"  , group: 2, label: "Fish"   , level: 1 },
  { id: "carp"  , group: 2, label: "Carp"   , level: 2 },
  { id: "pike"  , group: 2, label: "Pikes"  , level: 2 }
]
var links = [
 { target: "mammal", source: "dog" , strength: 0.7 },
 { target: "mammal", source: "cat" , strength: 0.7 },
  { target: "mammal", source: "fox" , strength: 0.7 },
  { target: "mammal", source: "elk" , strength: 0.7 },
  { target: "insect", source: "ant" , strength: 0.7 },
  { target: "insect", source: "bee" , strength: 0.7 },
  { target: "fish"  , source: "carp", strength: 0.7 },
  { target: "fish"  , source: "pike", strength: 0.7 },
  { target: "cat"   , source: "elk" , strength: 0.1 },
  { target: "carp"  , source: "ant" , strength: 0.1 },
  { target: "elk"   , source: "bee" , strength: 0.1 },
  { target: "dog"   , source: "cat" , strength: 0.1 },
  { target: "fox"   , source: "ant" , strength: 0.1 },
 { target: "pike"  , source: "cat" , strength: 0.1 }
]
function getNodeColor(node) {
  return node.level === 1 ? 'red' : 'gray'
}
var width = window.innerWidth
var height = window.innerHeight
var svg = d3.select('svg')
svg.attr('width', width).attr('height', height)
// simulation setup with all forces
var linkForce = d3
  .forceLink()
  .id(function (link) { return link.id })
  .strength(function (link) { return link.strength })
var simulation = d3
  .forceSimulation()
  .force('link', linkForce)
  .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-120))
  .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
var linkElements = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "links")
  .selectAll("line")
  .data(links)
  .enter().append("line")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
   .attr("stroke", "rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2)")
var nodeElements = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "nodes")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .attr("fill", getNodeColor)
var textElements = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "texts")
  .selectAll("text")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("text")
    .text(function (node) { return  node.label })
   .attr("font-size", 15)
   .attr("dx", 15)
    .attr("dy", 4)
simulation.nodes(nodes).on('tick', () => {
  nodeElements
    .attr('cx', function (node) { return node.x })
    .attr('cy', function (node) { return node.y })
  textElements
    .attr('x', function (node) { return node.x })
    .attr('y', function (node) { return node.y })
  linkElements
    .attr('x1', function (link) { return link.source.x })
    .attr('y1', function (link) { return link.source.y })
    .attr('x2', function (link) { return link.target.x })
    .attr('y2', function (link) { return link.target.y })
})
simulation.force("link").links(links)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

**Question 2**: When the source of a link doesn't match the node, it is throwing error, how can I avoid the error?

http://jsfiddle.net/3hL48pxg/5/

[image]

```js
var nodes = [
  { id: "mammals", group: 0, label: "Mammals", level: 1 },
  { id: "mammals", group: 0, label: "Mammals", level: 1 },
  { id: "dog"   , group: 0, label: "Dogs"   , level: 2 },
  { id: "cat"   , group: 0, label: "Cats"   , level: 2 },
  { id: "fox"   , group: 0, label: "Foxes"  , level: 2 },
  { id: "elk"   , group: 0, label: "Elk"    , level: 2 },
  { id: "insect", group: 1, label: "Insects", level: 1 },
  { id: "ant"   , group: 1, label: "Ants"   , level: 2 },
  { id: "bee"   , group: 1, label: "Bees"   , level: 2 },
  { id: "fish"  , group: 2, label: "Fish"   , level: 1 },
  { id: "carp"  , group: 2, label: "Carp"   , level: 2 },
  { id: "pike"  , group: 2, label: "Pikes"  , level: 2 }
]
var links = [
 { target: "mammals1111", source: "dog" , strength: 0.7 },
 { target: "mammals", source: "cat" , strength: 0.7 },
  { target: "mammals", source: "fox" , strength: 0.7 },
  { target: "mammals", source: "elk" , strength: 0.7 },
  { target: "insect", source: "ant" , strength: 0.7 },
  { target: "insect", source: "bee" , strength: 0.7 },
  { target: "fish"  , source: "carp", strength: 0.7 },
  { target: "fish"  , source: "pike", strength: 0.7 },
  { target: "cat"   , source: "elk" , strength: 0.1 },
  { target: "carp"  , source: "ant" , strength: 0.1 },
  { target: "elk"   , source: "bee" , strength: 0.1 },
  { target: "dog"   , source: "cat" , strength: 0.1 },
  { target: "fox"   , source: "ant" , strength: 0.1 },
 { target: "pike"  , source: "cat" , strength: 0.1 }
]
function getNodeColor(node) {
  return node.level === 1 ? 'red' : 'gray'
}
var width = window.innerWidth
var height = window.innerHeight
var svg = d3.select('svg')
svg.attr('width', width).attr('height', height)
// simulation setup with all forces
var linkForce = d3
  .forceLink()
  .id(function (link) { return link.id })
  .strength(function (link) { return link.strength })
var simulation = d3
  .forceSimulation()
  .force('link', linkForce)
  .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-120))
  .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
var linkElements = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "links")
  .selectAll("line")
  .data(links)
  .enter().append("line")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
   .attr("stroke", "rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2)")
var nodeElements = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "nodes")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .attr("fill", getNodeColor)
var textElements = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "texts")
  .selectAll("text")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("text")
    .text(function (node) { return  node.label })
   .attr("font-size", 15)
   .attr("dx", 15)
    .attr("dy", 4)
simulation.nodes(nodes).on('tick', () => {
  nodeElements
    .attr('cx', function (node) { return node.x })
    .attr('cy', function (node) { return node.y })
  textElements
    .attr('x', function (node) { return node.x })
    .attr('y', function (node) { return node.y })
  linkElements
    .attr('x1', function (link) { return link.source.x })
    .attr('y1', function (link) { return link.source.y })
    .attr('x2', function (link) { return link.target.x })
    .attr('y2', function (link) { return link.target.y })
})
simulation.force("link").links(links)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Both your questions can be explained by these lines in the [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/src/link.js#L9):

```
function find(nodeById, nodeId) {
    var node = nodeById.get(nodeId);
    if (!node) throw new Error("missing: " + nodeId);
    return node;
}
```

#### Question 1

Regarding question 1, it's ease to see that `nodeById` is a map, since we have `nodeById.get`. It's a D3 map, not a vanilla JavaScript map, but they are almost the same.

In a D3 map, if you use two identical keys, the last one will override the first one. According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection/blob/master/README.md#maps):

> If the map previously had an entry for the same key string, the old entry is replaced with the new value.

Therefore, `node` in the snippet above will always refer to the second `mammal`.

**Solution**: use unique IDs.

#### Question 2

Regarding the question 2, the issue is even more obvious: If the code doesn't find the respective node, an error is thrown:

```
if (!node) throw new Error("missing: " + nodeId);
```

Which is the error that you'll see in your JSFiddle (look at the console). That's the expected behaviour.

**Solution**: always make sure that the links have correct source and targets.